# Scrolling Through Long Lists Such As Instagram

Tags: website, youtube, scrolling

this is not specifically an Instagram issue. It is about that system that some websites use to list things like videos and images, where you are given 20 or so images first, and then you have to scroll down to load another 20, and scroll down again to load another 20 and so on.

This seems to be the most common way of listing things on websites these days, but it means that if you want to see the oldest post on instagram (for example) you will have to scroll down sometimes through 10,000 images to get there. Not only does this take a lot of time, but usually you'll encounter an error half way through which will not let you load more images.

I hate this system, and I don't know why these websites don't implement a page system where you can choose to go to page 140/140 instead of manually scrolling through each one!

So, my question is: Is there a way around this? Is there a way to quickly scroll to the bottom of the listing, or to load every listed item at once? Maybe even with javascript or something, but I would like a solution that can be used in all instances of this type of listing system.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Unless the website implements such a feature, then no. The browser only knows and displays what it is given. It does not know there is more data "below."  I have come across this issue to and it can be annoying. I have a browser plugin called [Scroll to Top](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scroll-to-top/hegiignepmecppikdlbohnnbfjdoaghj?hl=en-US). It places a button on the page where if you click it, it will scroll the browser to the top. If you click it again, it will scroll to the bottom, where new data will be loaded. I can then click the button several times to expand the page a decent amount. However, if you are scrolling far back, that might not work for you.